# Algorithm for selecting items from a list, against a set budget, based on item preference (rank), item price, and number of items selected

Tags: algorithms

New to algorithmic thinking so looking for some guidance – especially as there might be multiple approaches to this.

Say you have a list of 100 distinct items. These items are ranked in order of preference. Their prices range from ~1 to ~100 USD. You have a fixed budget of 30 USD in one month.

eg. (in order of preference)

- 1: Item A (35.92 USD)
- 2: Item F (10.74 USD)
- 3: Item Q (100.62 USD)
- 4: Item L (00.84 USD)
- ...
- 100: Item T (25.23 USD)

What would be the the approach for selecting the 'optimum' items to buy with your fixed budget in a given month, based on item ranks, item prices, and a desire to buy as many items as possible with your budget? For clarity, your budget can roll over to the next month to be used to purchase an item > 30 USD. You will be making a selection every month, indefinitely, removing items from the list over time.

eg. should a 30 USD budget be used to buy many items in the 0-5 USD range (as highly ranked as possible), be used to buy the highest ranked item possible <30 USD, or be rolled over to buy a highly ranked item >30 USD?

Do I need to set relative weights for each of these parameters in order to 'score' each selection (of one or more items)? And decide the optimum selection based on this score?

Any input appreciated (providing this makes sense!). Thanks.

Comment: As it stands, this question is not well-defined.  Please define "optimum".  What metric or metric will you use to compare two different candidate solutions?  Just knowing a preference ranking on items is not enough to know whether one set of items is better than another set of items.  Until you choose that, it is premature to ask for an algorithm to solve the problem.  We can't choose that for you, because it depends on what you want.

Comment: Understand and appreciate the feedback. 

I probably need to go back the drawing board — hope to come back and be able to define the question properly. Thanks.